# How do you real-time plot a colormap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap, real-time-data, real-time-updates

I am currently working on creating a Qt window with 3 matplotlib colormaps.

The process is something like this:

1. The user will input the x and y values of the plots into a GUI (each plot will have the same x and y values).
2. These values will be converted and then sent to a microprocessor which will communicate with both a DAC and ADC (Instrument "stuff" happens on the "backend" between the DAC and ADC, i.e. a spectrum analyzer takes noise measurements).
3. For each x and y point, we will receive one z value for each colormap. To emphasize: This means that each subplot will need to update simultaneously.

I am currently working on the script that will real-time graph these colormaps in a Qt window as the data is being taken. I can find readily accessible resources on how to real-time plot line graphs; however, I am unable to find anything for colormaps. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import sys
import time
import random

import numpy as np

from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtWidgets
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (
    FigureCanvas, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable


# Quick note, this will need to be a widget class in the final version so it can be run from the kalamari main window
# but I think that will just change how the class is initalized

class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # set up the window
        super().__init__()
        self._main = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._main)
        # It seems as though this layout is what is going to allow me to
        # orient all 3 subplots onto the same y axis
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self._main)

        # create seperate canvas objects
        first_canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(9, 6)))
        layout.addWidget(NavigationToolbar(first_canvas, self))
        layout.addWidget(first_canvas)

        second_canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(9, 3)))
        layout.addWidget(second_canvas)
        layout.addWidget(NavigationToolbar(second_canvas, self))

        # add subplots to the first canvas
        self._first_axs = first_canvas.figure.subplots(1, 3)

        # create data and colormap

        # Here I replace X and Y with coordinate vectors which are just np.linspace
        x = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
        y = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
        # For the final version you can use x for flux and y for biases and then have
        # each row of z be the voltages, such that:
        # z[i,j] is V(bias[j], flux[i])
        # Then here is the data I will use to determine the color,
        # this needs to have the same dimension as the coordinates
        z = np.random.rand(10, 10)

        custom_cmap = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
            "custom", ["#00008B", "blue", "cyan", "green", "yellow", "orange", "red", "#8B0000"])

        # access each subplot using regular indexing
        self._first_axs[0].set_title(
            'I' + u'\u209B' + u'\u2092' + u'\u209C', size=40)
        self._first_axs[1].set_title(
            'dI' + u'\u209B' + u'\u2092' + u'\u209C' + '/dt', size=40)
        self._first_axs[2].set_title('Noise', size=40)

        # plot data and create colorbars
        self.plot1 = self._first_axs[0].contourf(
            x, y, z, levels=20, cmap=custom_cmap)
        self.plot2 = self._first_axs[1].contourf(
            x, y, z, levels=20, cmap=custom_cmap)
        self.plot3 = self._first_axs[2].contourf(
            x, y, z, levels=20, cmap=custom_cmap)
        self.cbar1 = first_canvas.figure.colorbar(
            self.plot1, ax=self._first_axs[0], orientation='horizontal')
        self.cbar2 = first_canvas.figure.colorbar(
            self.plot2, ax=self._first_axs[1], orientation='horizontal')
        self.cbar3 = first_canvas.figure.colorbar(
            self.plot3, ax=self._first_axs[2], orientation='horizontal')

        # make the second canvas a dynamic plot
        self._second_ax = second_canvas.figure.subplots()
        t = list(range(50))
        self.yData = [random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(50)]

        # Set up a Line2D.
        self._line, = self._second_ax.plot(t, self.yData)
        self._timer = second_canvas.new_timer(50)
        self._timer.add_callback(self._update_canvas)
        self._timer.start()

    def _update_canvas(self):
        t = list(range(50))
        self.yData = self.yData[1:] + [random.randint(0, 10)]
        # set line data
        self._line.set_data(t, self.yData)
        self._line.figure.canvas.draw()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Check for open QApplication.instance()
    qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if not qapp:
        qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    # run it!
    app = ApplicationWindow()
    app.show()
    app.activateWindow()
    app.raise_()
    qapp.exec()
```

This code currently produces 1 Qt window with 2 separate "canvases". The first canvas is the 3 colormaps, the second is a line plot that real-time graphs.

#### Top Plots

- These are static, but I would like them to be dynamic.
- **Would anybody be able to help me determine how to real-time plot these colormaps as I am collecting data?**

[image]

#### Bottom Plot

- This runs in real-time
- I do not need the line graph for my purposes. It is just there as a reference to real-time plotting methods.

[image]

Comment: Are your x and y arrays constant? What is stopping you from replotting the contours with new data every update call?

Comment: Hi Jared. My x and y arrays are constant. Forgive my inexperience. Would you be able to point me in the direction of what you are referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try replotting the contour with every update call. I use `ax.cla()` to clear the current plot, before plotting new information. This script is an example of what that might look like.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rng = np.random.default_rng()

N = 25
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, N)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, N)

Niter = 25
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect(1)
for _ in range(Niter):
    ax.cla()
    z = rng.uniform(size=(N,N))
    ax.contourf(x, y, z)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    renderer = fig.canvas.renderer
    ax.draw(renderer)
    plt.pause(0.01)
```

[image]

Comment: @Stephanie Howell, did this answer your question?

Comment: Hi @jared, this does answer my question. Thank you!